# Datepicker calendar doesn't go away when tab key pressed

Tags: javascript, datepicker, calendar

I asked a question a few days ago about this, and got some great feedback about validation of the date format. I haven't put that code into my script yet because I need to get the datepicker working right first. Here is my issue...I have the following code in my view to use datepicker to get some date fields:

```
$(function () {
    $('.datepicker2').datepicker()
    .on('changeDate', function (ev) {
     $('.datepicker2').datepicker('hide');
 });
    ForceDatePickerFormat();
});
function ForceDatePickerFormat() {
    $(".datepicker2").on("blur", function (e) {

        var date, day, month, newYear, value, year;
        value = e.target.value;
        if (value.search(/(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)/) !== -1) {
            date = e.target.value.split("/");
            month = date[0];
            day = date[1];
            year = date[2];
            if (year === "") {
                year = "0";
            }
            if (year.length < 4 || year.length > 4) {
                alert("Date year must be 4 digits");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

So, this just brings up the datepicker when the user clicks on a field, and then checks to make sure the date has a 4-digit year. This works pretty well except for:

1. The calendar doesn't go away when the tab key is pressed. This is a problem because the tab key takes the cursor down to the next field, but it is covered up by the popup calendar box that is still there!
2. The code for the validation works (if they type 2 digits for year, it gives them an alert), unless they pressed the tab key first and it moved down to the next field. In that case, they can click "OK" and go back to the original field, the datepicker box doesn't come up and they can type whatever they want in the field without getting an error.

Is there a way to just disable the tab key while they are focused on any datepicker fields? Or, close the popup when the tab key is pressed (doesn't help #2)?

Thanks for any help! I've spent hours and hours and hours trying to make this thing work right! I've read ALL of the threads on datepicker that exist on the web...none of them were exactly what I needed here.

Comment: I added the following code right before the validation function:
        $('.datepicker2').on('keydown',  function (e) {
                var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
                if (keyCode == 9) {
                    $('.datepicker2').datepicker('hide');
                }
            });
which hides the calendar if the tab key is pressed to go to the next field. The only other thing that I need is the ability to then return back to the original field being input if the format is invalid. Any thoughts?